# Samsung pass sdk change standby text in fingerprint dialog

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile-sdk, android-fingerprint-api

I'm using pass sdk v1.2.1, according to [programming guide](http://developer.samsung.com/html/techdoc/ProgrammingGuide_Pass.pdf) there is a method to change the standby text showing in the fingerprint dialog. The guide say that you have to check if the feature `Spass.DEVICE_FINGERPRINT_AVAILABLE_PASSWORD` is enable to call `changeStandbyString`, something like this:

```
 if(pass.isFeatureEnabled(Spass.DEVICE_FINGERPRINT_AVAILABLE_PASSWORD)) {
    mSpassFingerprint.changeStandbyString("Touch your fingerprint or press the button for launching own menu”);
 }
```

I try to use it on Galaxy S5 with Android 6.0 and Galaxy S5 Android 5.x.x in both I get the exception

```
IllegalStateException: setStandbyString is not supported.
```

What it seem a little odd is that the exception gets called if a method inside `changeStandbyString` returns true which turns out is the same method called when you check

```
isFeatureEnabled(Spass.DEVICE_FINGERPRINT_AVAILABLE_PASSWORD);
```

so looks like something is wrong, any idea?

This is the code generated when debugging with android studio:

```
public void changeStandbyString(String var1) {
        this.f();
        if(this.d()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("setStandbyString is not supported.");
        } else if(var1 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the standby text passed is null.");
        } else if(var1.length() > 100) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the standby text passed is longer than 100 characters.");
        } else {
            this.m = var1;
        }
    }

public boolean isFeatureEnabled(int var1) {
        if(this.a == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("initialize() is not Called first.");
        } else {
            switch(var1) {
            case 0:
                return this.a.a();
            case 1:
            case 2:
                return this.a.b();
            case 3:
                return this.a.c();
            case 4:
                return this.a.d();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("type passed is not valid");
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that the method `d()` is the one called in both situation, when you check for the featured to see if is enable and when you change the text, looks like it should be `if(!this.d())` in `changeStandbyString`, as it does in others methods like:

```
public void setDialogTitle(String var1, int var2) {
        this.f();
        if(!this.b()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("setDialogTitle is not supported.");
        } else if(var1 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the titletext passed is null.");
        } else if(var1.length() > 256) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the title text passed is longer than 256 characters.");
        } else if(var2 >>> 24 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("alpha value is not supported in the titleColor.");
        } else {
            this.f = var1;
            this.g = var2 + -16777216;
        }
    }
```

Here `throw new IllegalStateException("setDialogTitle is not supported.");` only happens if `this.b()` returns false which is the method called from `isFeaturedEnabled` when the flag is `Spass.DEVICE_FINGERPRINT_CUSTOMIZED_DIALOG` (`Spass.DEVICE_FINGERPRINT_CUSTOMIZED_DIALOG = 2`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Programming Guide doc is wrong. If `isFeatureEnabled(Spass. DEVICE_FINGERPRINT_AVAILABLE_PASSWORD)` returns false, then this function can be activated. You can check out the [code samples](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass#samples) to take a closer look of how use this feature.